# WordPress Paginate custom post type on index page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination, custom-post-type

In my WordPress Template, I'd like to have custom post type pagination on my index page.
The problem with code below, is that when i click "older posts" link, it redirects to /page/2 URL, and in results it shows 404 error.

Here's my custom post type register code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'video_news',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Video News' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Video News' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array('category'),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'videos'),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
        )
    );
}
```

Here's my WP_Query loop code:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'video_news', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="pagination">
    <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &raquo;' ); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'No results' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a static front page?

If so change

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

to

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

If you're not using a static front page you may want to consider using the pre_get_posts hook instead. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Insert the following into functions.php. If you go this route remove your custom query from the index template file.

```
function my_home_video_news_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_home() ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'video_news' );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_video_news_query' );
```

Comment: I've tried switching between 'page' and 'paged' before but it didn't work.

Comment: How many regular posts do you have? Less than the number per page in your settings? I have modified my answer by the way to include the pre_get_posts solution.

Answer (score 0):

looks fine to me.

Did you check the Permalink settings?

Comment: I did 'reset' the permalinks by changing them back and forth (the custom page archive works), using Post Name besides that. Should i use any optional settings?

Comment: which setting did you pick for your permalinks?

Comment: %post-name% althoug i did reset it after registering new custom posty type.

Answer (score 0):

> Insted of this

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &raquo;' ); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</div>
```

> Use this

```
<div class="pagination">
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
</div>
```